# a function doesn't work in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

this developed function works with any server but doesn't work in app engine. 
because it has a function or functions which don't work by google app engine or cause a problem.

Any solution for this ?!! or any alternatives ?!!

```
/**
 * get_redirect_url()
 * Gets the address that the provided URL redirects to,
 * or FALSE if there's no redirect. 
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return string
 */
function get_redirect_url($url){
    $redirect_url = null; 

    $url_parts = @parse_url($url);
    if (!$url_parts) return false;
    if (!isset($url_parts['host'])) return false; //can't process relative URLs
    if (!isset($url_parts['path'])) $url_parts['path'] = '/';

    $sock = fsockopen($url_parts['host'], (isset($url_parts['port']) ? (int)$url_parts['port'] : 80), $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$sock) return false;

    $request = "HEAD " . $url_parts['path'] . (isset($url_parts['query']) ? '?'.$url_parts['query'] : '') . " HTTP/1.1\r\n"; 
    $request .= 'Host: ' . $url_parts['host'] . "\r\n"; 
    $request .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n"; 
    fwrite($sock, $request);
    $response = '';
    while(!feof($sock)) $response .= fread($sock, 8192);
    fclose($sock);

    if (preg_match('/^Location: (.+?)$/m', $response, $matches)){
        if ( substr($matches[1], 0, 1) == "/" )
            return $url_parts['scheme'] . "://" . $url_parts['host'] . trim($matches[1]);
        else
            return trim($matches[1]);

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should work fine **if** the GAE-side server supports HEAD in redirects.

Many GAE apps choose (or rather default into) no support for HEAD in redirects, because of what I consider a design defect in the otherwise-great `webapp2` open-source lightweight framework that's quite popular on GAE).

Anyway, if *whatever* server you're addressing doesn't support HEAD in redirects, quite independently if it runs on GAE or not, if it uses `webapp2` or not, &c -- the root cause of **why** it doesn't support HEAD in redirects doesn't matter at all! -- the only workaround I can think of is using `GET` instead (assuming of course the server **does** properly support redirects in `GET`, otherwise, no solution, I think:-).

Yes, what a waste (if the body's big and you don't care for it at all).  A good alternative would be proposing a patch to the `webapp2` maintainers list at https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/googleappengine/python/+/c06f40e29990868cc01795c88aeb0c42b8d9e395/lib/webapp2/AUTHORS ...

Answer (score 0):

The cause simply is that free app engine doesn't support fsockopen() function , 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/sockets/

and I have read this in other websites.

so I used this function and it works

```
function getRedirectUrl ($url) {
  stream_context_set_default(array(
      'http' => array(
          'method' => 'HEAD'
      )
  ));
  $headers = get_headers($url, 1);
  if ($headers !== false && isset($headers['Location'])) {
      return $headers['Location'];
  }
  return false;
}
```